# CKEditor add more symbols

Tags: ckeditor, special-characters

How can I add more "custom" symbols in the Insert Special Character panel please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note this can be done in the config file as well:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-specialChars

Comment: Thanks Michael. This is a better way of doing it.

Comment: There's no directory such as "plugins/specialchar/plugin.js"

Comment: @Vijin That link was to v3 documentation, I've just updated it to v4.

Answer (score 4):

In your config file => **config.js**

CKeditor Documentation: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-specialChars

```
config.specialChars = [ '&quot;', '&rsquo;', [ '&custom;', 'Custom label' ] ];
config.specialChars = config.specialChars.concat( [ '&quot;', [ '&rsquo;', 'Custom label' ] ] );
```

If you want to add special characters (Greek for example):

```
config.specialChars = config.specialChars.concat( [ [ '&alpha;', 'alpha' ],
      [ '&beta;', 'beta' ],
      [ '&gamma;', 'gamma' ],
      [ '&delta;', 'delta' ],
      [ '&epsilon;', 'epsilon' ],
      [ '&zeta;', 'zeta' ],
      [ '&eta;', 'eta' ],
      [ '&theta;', 'theta' ],
      [ '&iota;', 'iota' ],
      [ '&kappa;', 'kappa' ],
      [ '&lambda;', 'lambda' ],
      [ '&mu;', 'mu' ],
      [ '&nu;', 'nu' ],
      [ '&xi;', 'xi' ],
      [ '&omicron;', 'omicron' ],
      [ '&pi;', 'pi' ],
      [ '&rho;', 'rho' ],
      [ '&sigma;', 'sigma' ],
      [ '&tau;', 'tau' ],
      [ '&upsilon;', 'upsilon' ],
      [ '&phi;', 'phi' ],
      [ '&chi;', 'chi' ],
      [ '&psi;', 'psi' ],
      [ '&omega;', 'omega' ] ] );
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding custom symbols is actually pretty easy. Within the ckeditor folder go to the file:

```
ckeditor/plugins/specialchar/dialogs/specialchar.js
```

You'll see a large code block halfway through the file containing a ton of entity codes, the last one is `&asymp;` - after that one, add any new ones you want separated by commas and surrounded in single quotes. ,'new','new'.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Open up your **config.js** file,

If you want to insert male(♂) symbol use the below code in the config file,

```
config.specialChars = config.specialChars.concat('♂');
```

If you want to insert male symbol with custom label,

```
config.specialChars = config.specialChars.concat(['♂', 'Male']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a CKeditor 4 installed, in my case I had to go to root > assets > backend > ckeditor > ckeditor.js

The code looks like this

[image: Code as it was]

I then added this patch
[image: γ δ ε ζ η θ ι κ λ μ ν ξ ο π ρ σ τ υ φ χ ψ ω]

and it works